# Repeat an hourly task in org-agenda grid

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date, agenda-custom-commands

Why an hourly scheduled (repeating) task would appear only once in org-agenda grid? I assumed that this entry should appear again (at 17:09, 18:09, 19:09...).

[image]

This org-agenda is generated with:

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
                     ("o" "overview"
        ((agenda "" (
                  (org-agenda-overriding-header "")
                  (org-agenda-span '8)
                  ))
   ...
  )
```